# The intuition behind the solution to this question?

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if A and B are any non-empty sets with $a+b \leq \alpha$ for each $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ the A and B are bounded above and $\sup A + \sup B \leq \alpha$? (Reference: Yet another introduction to Analysis by Victor Bryant, page 13, question 2(ii)).

I have a formal solution to this question but I am not able to see the correctness of the solution at the intuitive level. The author also says that there are many ways to prove it, by not writing the author's solution here I hope to get alternate solutions, which may be more understandable to me.

**Very specifically, how to think about this question and its solution at the intuitive level? Please share your intuitive explanations instead of plain formal solutions.**

Thank You.

Comment: A simple way to start is to take $A$ and $B$ to be finite sets with only a few elements. First take some concrete cases, e.g. $A = \{0, 2,4\}, B = \{-2,-1\}$. Then think about a proof where $A$ and $B$ are both arbitrary finite sets (so $\sup$ becomes $\max$). You can also take the proof given by the author and rewrite it for the case where $A$ and $B$ are both finite sets or go through the proof steps for a concrete example such as the one suggested above. I realize that this is really a suggestion for you to develop your own intuition rather than an intuitive explanation.

Comment: I thought of the finite sets, but I could not take the same reasoning to infinite sets. For example, in finite sets I can think in terms of max or min which are contained in the set but in infinite sets I have sup which may not be contained in the set. So will the inequality hold even in case of supA+supB. Such types of confusions were cluttering my mind.

Comment: To go from finite to infinite sets (sup to max), use some of the techniques from the two answers below. That is, instead of picking elements from these sets that are maximal, use sequences from these sets that converge to the suprema.

Comment: Note that there are two intuitions that can be used. One is the intuition about formal symbolic manipulation of logic statements, which can be useful sometimes. The other kind of intuition is the one you're looking for here. It's best to have both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that does not use any sequences whatsoever, and hence is the "simplest" in some sense.

If $\sup(A) + \sup(B) > α$: [See what happens when the sum of the sup is too big.]

Let $c = \sup(A) + \sup(B) - α$. [Look at the discrepancy.]

Let $x \in A$ such that $x > \sup(A) - \frac{1}{2} c$. [Choose $x$ close enough to $\sup(A)$.]

Let $y \in B$ such that $y > \sup(B) - \frac{1}{2} c$. [Same for $y$.]

Then $x+y > \sup(A)+\sup(B) - c = α$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \le α$.

What happened? When we assumed wrongly that the sum of the sup was bigger than the bound on all possible pair sum, we forced at least one of the sups to be too big, and so picking close enough elements created a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

*First part:* Fix an $\tilde b \in B$. You have $a + \tilde b \le \alpha \iff a \le \alpha - \tilde b$ for each $a \in A$. Thus $A$ is bounded above by $\alpha - \tilde b$. Analogously you can prove that $B$ is bounded above.

*Second part:* From the definition of the supremum you can conclude, that there are sequences $(a_n)$ in $A$ and $(b_n)$ in $B$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \sup A$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = \sup B$. Thus $$\sup A + \sup B = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n  = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \underbrace{(a_n + b_n)}_{\le \alpha} \le \alpha$$

Comment: I am confused about the underlying assumptions of the solution in Second part. From first part, all I know that sequence is bounded from above and from that I can conclude that the sequence has a least upper bound. So, $supA \leq \alpha - b$ and $supB \leq \alpha - a$. So, $supA + supB \leq \alpha + \alpha - (a+b)$. But then $\alpha - (a+b) > 0, thus  \alpha + \alpha - (a+b) > \alpha$, so I am not able to compare $supA + supB$ and $\alpha$? I am not sure where I am making the mistake?